# Python - how to randomly select instances from a class

Tags: python

i need to randomly select 2 instances from a class node:

[Class node:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iax6i.png)

class node:

```
def __init__(self, parent = None, length_to_parent = None, name = None, left = None, right = None, internal = 1, root = 0):
    self.parent = parent # parent node
    self.length_to_parent = length_to_parent # length to the parent node
    self.name = name # name of the node (to-be-defined name if external node(leaf), None if internal node)
    self.left = left # left child
    self.right = right # right child
    self.internal = internal # indicate if the node is an internal node
    self.root = root
```

I'm thinking of storing all instances from node in a list then use random.choose or random.shuffle to randomly pick 2 nodes from the list.

But I dont know how to store instances into a list though... Anyone help please!!! thanks

Comment: We all start from somewhere, so I'm going to help you out on some basic guidelines to get help. 1) Post snippets of your code (indented with ctrl+k), screenshots do not help. 2) describe what you've done. 3) Expected outputs will help.

Comment: You can just keep objects in a list: `[your_object() for _ in range(how_many_you_want)]` and then use random.select from that list.

Answer (score 1):

You can store instances on a list just like anything else.

```
import random
lst = []
new_node = node(parent,length... etc)

lst.append(new_node)

# assuming you have > 2 nodes:
# pick two random nodes, store in another lst
random_selection = [random.choice(lst) for x in range(2)]
```

Was there anything specific you're asking?

Comment: Yup that's better, upvoted, but to improve, you can also add another example `random.choices(lst, k=2)` and specify it's for python 3.6 only :)

Comment: @abccd Thats true! Thank you for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this "node" of yours is part of a binary tree.
In that case, you can just iterate through your tree and store references in a running list.

Something along the lines of:

```
arr = []
# Perform tree traversal.
traverse(root_node, arr)
# Now, do something here with the list!

def traverse(node, arr):
    # Traverse the left subtree
    if(node.left is not None):
        traverse(node.left, arr)
    # Traverse the right subtree
    if(node.right is not None):
        traverse(node.right, arr) 
    # Append the node! It can be appended like any other item in the list.
    arr.append(node)
```

You should be able to append nodes (like anything else) to the list, and then select your elements randomly as required.

Comment: Please don't cal a list `list`. You overwrite the function by the same name.

Comment: Whoops, good catch @dawg! I'm not a main python developer :) Edited!

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class variable that holds all the nodes (which are added at the end of `__init__`), and a class method to get two at random:

```
import random

class Node:
    node_instances = []
    def __init__(self, parent = None, length_to_parent = None, name = None, left = None, right = None, internal = 1, root = 0):
        self.parent = parent # parent node
        self.length_to_parent = length_to_parent # length to the parent node
        self.name = name # name of the node (to-be-defined name if external node(leaf), None if internal node)
        self.left = left # left child
        self.right = right # right child
        self.internal = internal # indicate if the node is an internal node
        self.root = root
        Node.node_instances.append(self)

   @classmethod
   def get_random_instances(cls):
      return random.sample(cls.node_instances, 2)
```

Which you can use like:

```
n_random = Node.get_random_instances()
```